# Mostrar los números más pequeños de distintos arrays

Tags: java

Tengo un código que tiene que mostrar por pantalla el ganador **(0)** y la ganadora **(1)** de la etapa (**el que menos minutos ha tardado**), este programa debe ser capaz de encontrarlo por si mismo. *Los datos son facilitados en los array.*

El código es el siguiente:

```
package javaapplication2;

public class Ejercicio10_UF1B {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dmatriz [][] = new int [10][4];
        int smatriz[][] = new int[10][4];
        int tmatriz[][] = new int[10][4];
        int ematriz[][] = new int[10][4];
        int menor = tmatriz[0][0];
        
        //DORSAL
        dmatriz [0][0] = 3457;
        dmatriz [1][0] = 3467;
        dmatriz [2][0] = 3568;
        dmatriz [3][0] = 3570;
        dmatriz [4][0] = 3571;
        dmatriz [5][0] = 3572;
        dmatriz [6][0] = 3573;
        dmatriz [7][0] = 3574;
        dmatriz [8][0] = 3575;
        dmatriz [9][0] = 3576;
        
        //SEXO
        smatriz [0][1] = 1;
        smatriz [1][1] = 1;
        smatriz [2][1] = 0;
        smatriz [3][1] = 0;
        smatriz [4][1] = 1;
        smatriz [5][1] = 0;
        smatriz [6][1] = 0;
        smatriz [7][1] = 0;
        smatriz [8][1] = 1;
        smatriz [9][1] = 0;
        
        //EDAD
        ematriz [0][2] = 51;
        ematriz [1][2] = 32;
        ematriz [2][2] = 14;
        ematriz [3][2] = 12;
        ematriz [4][2] = 45;
        ematriz [5][2] = 17;
        ematriz [6][2] = 12;
        ematriz [7][2] = 30;
        ematriz [8][2] = 24;
        ematriz [9][2] = 57;
        
        //MINUTOS
        tmatriz [0][3] = 52;
        tmatriz [1][3] = 41;
        tmatriz [2][3] = 39;
        tmatriz [3][3] = 63;
        tmatriz [4][3] = 38;
        tmatriz [5][3] = 46;
        tmatriz [6][3] = 59;
        tmatriz [7][3] = 42;
        tmatriz [8][3] = 77;
        tmatriz [9][3] = 48;
        
        for (int x = 0; x < tmatriz.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y <tmatriz[x].length; y++){
                int numeroActual = tmatriz[x][y];
                if (numeroActual < menor){
                    menor = numeroActual;   
                }
            }
            System.out.println("El menor número es: " + menor);
        }
        
    }
}
```

El problema es que no soy capaz de imprimir por pantalla el ganador (0) y ganadora (1) con los menores tiempos. He intentado hacer en este código, enseñando el menor tiempo (siendo generalizado - 0 y 1) intentando ir por partes para ver si conseguía hacerlo, pero la idea es imprimir por pantalla al ganador y ganadora con los menores tiempos.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Una matriz de 10x4 tiene 40 elementos. 10 filas y en cada fila 4 elementos. Y tú solo estás rellenando 10. No entiendo esos datos así inicializados. Si es así, te sobra la segunda dimensión en todas las matrices.

Comment: Hola, no te entiendo, a que te refieres con rellenando 10?

Comment: Te lo explico en una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te digo en los comentarios, me parece que no te hacen falta matrices de dos dimensiones sino arrays de una sola dimensión:

```
int dmatriz[] = new int [10];
int smatriz[] = new int[10];
int tmatriz[] = new int[10];
int ematriz[] = new int[10];
```

También vas a necesitar dos variables para el menor de cada sexo, así como el dorsal de cada uno:

```
    int menor_masculino = 99999;
    int menor_femenido = 999999;
    int dorsal_masculino = 0;
    int dorsal_femenino = 0;
```

Para inicializar los arrays, casí como lo tenías, pero ahora solo tenemos una dimensión:

```
    //DORSAL
    dmatriz [0] = 3457;
    dmatriz [1] = 3467;
    dmatriz [2] = 3568;
    dmatriz [3] = 3570;
    dmatriz [4] = 3571;
    dmatriz [5] = 3572;
    dmatriz [6] = 3573;
    dmatriz [7] = 3574;
    dmatriz [8] = 3575;
    dmatriz [9] = 3576;
    
    //SEXO
    smatriz [0] = 1;
    smatriz [1] = 1;
    smatriz [2] = 0;
    smatriz [3] = 0;
    smatriz [4] = 1;
    smatriz [5] = 0;
    smatriz [6] = 0;
    smatriz [7] = 0;
    smatriz [8] = 1;
    smatriz [9] = 0;
    
    //EDAD
    ematriz [0] = 51;
    ematriz [1] = 32;
    ematriz [2] = 14;
    ematriz [3] = 12;
    ematriz [4] = 45;
    ematriz [5] = 17;
    ematriz [6] = 12;
    ematriz [7] = 30;
    ematriz [8] = 24;
    ematriz [9] = 57;
    
    //MINUTOS
    tmatriz [0] = 52;
    tmatriz [1] = 41;
    tmatriz [2] = 39;
    tmatriz [3] = 63;
    tmatriz [4] = 38;
    tmatriz [5] = 46;
    tmatriz [6] = 59;
    tmatriz [7] = 42;
    tmatriz [8] = 77;
    tmatriz [9] = 48;
```

Y para encontrar el menor, hay que recorrer el array de tiempos, pero mirando también el de sexos.

```
for( int i = 0; i < tmatriz.length; i++) {
    if( smatriz[i] == 0) {
        if( tmatriz[i] < menor_masculino) {
            menor_masculino = tmatriz[i];
            dorsal_masculino = dmatriz[i];
        }
    } else {
        if( tmatriz[i] < menor_femenino) {
            menor_femenino = tmatriz[i];
            dorsal_femenino = dmatriz[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Al terminar el `for` tienes el tiempo menor para los dos sexos así como su dorsal.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ahora te entiendo ;)